# Optimal JAXB XJC code generation and optimal XML schema with inheritance

Tags: inheritance, xsd, jaxb, code-generation, xjc

There have been a lot of similar questions which focus on one aspect to optimize but each solution had an ugly downside.

Suppose I want to develop an XML schema (XSD) which allows the following documents and want to generate classes using XJC:

```
<Catalogue>
    <Book>...</Book>
    <Journal>...</Journal>
    <Book>...</Book>
    ...
</Catalogue>
```

The schema should model the type hierarchy (`Book` and `Journal` are subclasses of `Publication`). Naturally, this should also
be the case for the generated Java classes.

I tried the following approches which all have a major issue:

**1.) modeling Catalogue to contain a `xsd:choice` of all possible subtypes.**

```
<xsd:complexType name="Catalogue">
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="Book" />
        <xsd:element ref="Magazine" />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="Publication" abstract="true" type="Publication" />
<xsd:element name="Book" type="Book"/>
<xsd:element name="Magazine" type="Magazine"/>

<xsd:complexType name="Publication">
    <xsd:sequence></xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Book">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="Publication">
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
...
```

The problem here is that I have to mention all possible subtypes in the `choice` element which could be a lot in a real application. 
A minor issue is that, although the `Catalogue` attribute has the correct type `List<Publication>` it has an ugly name `bookAndMagazine`.
Because of the redundant schema definition, not an option!

**2.) modeling Catalogue to contain a `xsd:sequence` of the parent class**

```
<xsd:complexType name="Catalogue">
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="Publication" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This does only work if the XML documents are formulated like `<Publication xsi:type="Book"...>` . Thus, not an option!

**3.) Use substitutionGroup like mentioned here http://www.xfront.com/ElementHierarchy.html**

```
<xsd:complexType name="Catalogue">
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="Publication" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="Publication" abstract="true" type="Publication" />
<xsd:element name="Book" type="Book" substitutionGroup="Publication"/>
<xsd:element name="Magazine" type="Magazine" substitutionGroup="Publication"/>

<xsd:complexType name="Publication">
    <xsd:sequence></xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Book">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="Publication">
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
...
```

Here, the code generation is the issue because the inner element of `Catalogue` is mapped to `List<JaxbElement<? extends Publication>>` rather than
`List<Publication>` . Hence, also this isn't an option.

How to bring all my objectives together?:

- canonical, non-redundant schema which models inheritance (such as in **2.)** or **3.)**)
- simple and clean Java classes generated from this schema and which models inheritance (like in **2.)** and partly in **1.)** )
- clean XML documents (not like in **2.)** )
- usage of standard JAXB and preferable not much binding metadata

And if there is no solution which matches all these objectives, which one would you prefer?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why option 3) is bad, and why `List<JaxbElement<? extends Publication>>` is not workable for you ? It's actually elegant: not only you have a JAXB object, but the JAXBElement<> wrapper gives you the fully-qualified element name. xml info

Comment: 1.) I want to use the generated class hierarchy across other application parts as kind of a domain model and I do not like to let them depend on JaxB types. 2) I am applying the XJC plugin jaxb-visitor which enriches the generated classes for the visitor pattern. The JaxbElement attributes break the natural way to traverse the document tree.

Comment: I also think option 3 is very ugly.  I prefer to remain close to pojo's and never need the stuff JAXBElement provides in this case since it is all one schema.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using something similar to your first option as I have never seen a cleaner solution to this problem.

**XSD**

```
<xs:element name="Publications" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Magazine" type="magazine"/>
        <xs:element name="Book" type="book"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

 <xs:complexType name="magazine">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:extension base="publication">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="issueName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
 </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="publication">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="book">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="publication">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

**JAVA**
This is the Java code I used to generate the above XSD.

```
@XmlElements({
  @XmlElement(name="Magazine", type=Magazine.class),
  @XmlElement(name="Book", type=Book.class)
})
@XmlElementWrapper(name="Publications")
public List<Publication> publications;
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually also decided for 1.). However, in your example you are implementing the Java types including some annotations and generate the XSD from it. I am trying to go reverse. Developing the XSD and generating code. Interesting to see that the gernated XSD equals solution 1.)

Comment: One thing I would recommend you consider is that with option 1, you are stuck with these two sub-types and would have to rev up the XSD to support a new type in the future. There are ways to mitigate (for forward-compatibility), e.g. allow for an unknown type: <xsd:any namespace=”##any” minOccurs=”0”/>

Answer (score 0):

If you can start from the code (instead of the XSD) and are OK with using MOXY check out this [blog post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html).  It uses method 3 without the JAXBElement wrappers.  I'd love a way to do this starting with the XSD, but I haven't found it yet.