# XJC Java class generation for <xs:choice> element which is not unbounded

Tags: inheritance, xsd, jaxb, xjc

After this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10125966/602856) yesterday I have another question concerning inheritance in XML schema and XJC bindings.

Given the following choice element such that Book and Journal have a common parent type (`Publication`).

```
<xsd:choice >
    <xsd:element name="Book" type="Book" />
    <xsd:element name="Journal" type="Journal" />
</xsd:choice>
```

The Java class properties which are generated are like:

```
private Book book;
private Journal journal;
```

Since `<xsd:choice>` means that there might be either a `Book` or a `Journal` I would prefer

```
private Publication bookOrJournal;
```

If I had a list of Publications by setting `maxOccurs="unbounded"` in the choice element, it would work that way and I would get

```
private List<Publication> bookOrJournal;
```

How to achieve this with a non-collection property?

Answer (score 5):

You can using the following [XJC binding](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/10/jaxb.html?page=2) to achieve this.

```
<xs:complexType name="myClass">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
          <jaxb:property name="bookOrJournal"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:element name="Book" type="Book"/>
      <xs:element name="Journal" type="Journal"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

After executing `xjc <XSD File> -extension`, this generated the following Java class for me.

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "Book", type = Book.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "Journal", type = Journal.class)
})
protected Publication bookOrJournal;
```

To use the XJC binding, I added the following to the top of my XSD.

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  jaxb:version="1.0" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
```

Comment: Of course, these XJC directives can also be stored externally to the XSD in their own file, which is a clearer separation of concerns.

Comment: Sorry, this did not work as expected. When annotating like you did, I get an XJC error that XJC could not consider this customization because it is inconsistent or not assigned to the right element (can't quote the error because my XJC seems to speak German ;-) ) . When I move the annotation to e.g. the Book element than only the Book property is renamed to `publication` but there are still two properties, `publication` and `journal`

Comment: @rainer198 I added the full XSD def I used. See if that helps you debug your issue at all.